# At what point did computing go from mainly performance- and functionality-oriented to security-oriented? Why?

Tags: history, security

I realize this question may have a different answer for each field of computing (enterprise vs. business vs. personal vs. field equipment), but there should still be an objective point in time where this transition took place for each field of computing, and that's the goal of this question, knowing when that time was and what the events surrounding it looked like.

Back in the early days of (at least personal) computing, it seems like security wasn't much of a concern at all. Pretty much everything ran as "administrator" (or whatever the equivalent was for the machine in question), applications could read and write to wherever they wanted in RAM, a single buggy application could crash the entire system (looking at cooperative multitasking, yuck), and data was usually transmitted unencrypted. Even some systems designed to be somewhat multi-user (CP/M in particular) lacked all security - one could just switch to someone else's user and have full access to their stuff. The closest thing I can see to security in these old days of computing (at least for personal computing) was some simplistic forms of DRM (like the NES used for region locking). And even that didn't work particularly well.

Contrast this with modern-day computing, where well nigh everything that gets transmitted over the Internet is encrypted so strongly that even the most powerful computers known today can't break into it in a reasonable time span, security vulnerabilities are a big deal, systems are designed for multiple users and have privilege isolation, etc., etc. Even CPUs may have extra security features built into them (like Intel's SGX). It's become just part of how computing works.

I've not used enough old computers to know for sure, but AFAICT, in Windows, the transition from pure functionality-based computing to security-based computing happened somewhere around the time of Windows 2000, which had Administrator, Power User, and User security levels (IIRC), and an entire page in the Help manual on why using an Administrator account all the time was a bad idea. (Contrast this with Windows 95, which only had a username and password for logging you into the network, and would just give you total admin privileges to the physical system if you clicked "Cancel"...) I also remember reading about HTTPS and the now-obsolete S-HTTP in a very old HTML book (like, CSS was competing with DSSSL, old).

When did security really start becoming "on the radar" in the world of computing, and why? Was there ever a transition like this in the world of business computing (servers and mainframes), or have those always been security-oriented? What were some of the first security features, and what inspired their creation?

Edit: Also just realized another core part of the equation here - CPUs used to just be made faster and faster as technology and innovation would allow... which ultimately led to the mess we now know as Spectre/Meltdown (to the best of my knowledge). Now we have to be careful with these kind of things, oftentimes accepting dramatic performance cuts in so doing.

Comment: When "malware" became a thing, and users don't trust the software on their machines any more. When windows vista introduced UAC, malware is already out of control.

Comment: It happens when some technology becomes so widespread that you start to see adversarial activity on top of the originally cooperative activity in the earlier phases of the technology, so you need the tools to stop that activity. "Somewhere around the time of Windows 2000". Nah. Windows NT already had security levels, which imported it from earlier VAX operating systems.

Comment: For one thing, strong encryptions was quite impossible in the CP/M era. Simply not enough computer power to do it in a decent time. Today encrypting a message adds next to no time overhead (at least not in human terms) so why not do it?

Comment: Your question is implicitly talking about 'personal computers'. Computer security was a thing long before that, although since not so many computers were connected to a public network, the focus was different.

Comment: @another-dave I mentioned specifically "Back in the early days of (**at least personal**) computing..." and "Was there ever a transition like this in the world of business computing (servers and mainframes), or have those always been security-oriented?" I did want to know if professional computing had a similar transition or not, and if so, what it was like.

Comment: There are a LOT more computers these days, and they can exchange data much more easily.   Question is somewhat similar to "When did traffic laws become important?  People in the stone age did not have to worry about them" (as they were much fewer and more sparse and moved slower.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Well, yeah, that makes sense, the point of the question was more of "when was the crucial turning point when traffic laws became necessary and what did that look like". Admittedly, with traffic laws, that may have been rather boring, but with retrocomputing, it seems like an interesting topic.

Comment: As a datapoint I can mention that IRIX (the Unix on SGI machines) came without a password on the "lp" account so printing would work across machines.  Also Remote GL (as far as I remember) required unprotecting the X11 server.  These and many more required attention when my university department in the late 90'es got these machines and put them directly on the internet... (We had enough IPv4 addresses back then).

Comment: The Internet happened ......

Comment: It was a problem long before the internet. Virus's used to spread on the boot floppy of the Amiga - if you inserted an infected disk it the virus would load itself into memory and then replicate to the next disk. Many games had custom bootloaders so the virus would prevent them from booting. Boot sector backup software existed to mitigate this problem.

Comment: Can someone explain how this question is opinion-based? The fact that it has different answers depending on what field of computing you're looking at doesn't change the fact that it has an objective answer for each field of computing.

Comment: I don’t think the problem is chiefly with the date being different between subfields of computing… but because there in fact isn’t actually a clear demarcation point for any of them in the first place.

Comment: @user3840170 Maybe I'm just seeing how things work differently, then. To me, it looks like, with one version of Unix passwords were in plaintext root-readable-only, then they switched to encrypted world-readable, then to hashed root-readable-only. With Windows, one version of Windows was nearly devoid of security, the next version started implementing it (with the introduction of WinNT). It looked like a clear demarcation point to me, but if not, I guess then it is opinion-based.

Comment: And - just to clarify - CP/M was not multi-user oriented as such.  The "user" feature was more like a precursor to real directories allowing the user to organise files on a single floppy.  You typically had your own floppies even if the computer was shared.

Comment: Always. Computers were created to solve difficult mathematical problems in a reasonable time which granted them an early adoption in the military: from turret angle calculators in WWI to torpedo data computers and code breaking in WWII. But early computers needed human operators to actually work and it wasn't until random access memory and serious I/O control was added that computers could operate as stand-alone entities. It was at this point that Western militaries realized they had to prevent unauthorized access.

Comment: (2) A simple example would be the simultaneous-double-key switch to enable the launch of nuclear missiles at US silos. In the case of messaging, security was always a requirement for the militars, and talking at least for the US, put a large effort to it since WWII. When computers became powerful enough, they used them to cipher, decipher and sometimes break codes. During late WWII Germans realized eventually everything would be broken and what they needed to do was just give the breakers enough work to make the message obsolete by the time it was broken.

Comment: (3) The soviets inherited this concept after the war and added the concept of the one-time-pad, where the key is used only once and is replaced with a new one every time a message was prepared to send. A common key book they used was the Holy Bible, as it is a text so common they could find it wherever they went and, more important, its content was highly indexed at phrase level. Then they just xored it with the message to send. Xoring anything with a decent password gives the best entropy a cipher could provide, and by the 60s computers could do it quick.

Comment: @UncleBod (4) But microcomputers just weren't designed for the purpose of being secure. They were designed to be cheap enough to be sold to medium to small companies first, then the focus switched to homes. But still, there were methods. Any microcomputer with Intel 8080 bus (by extension all CP/M systems) could have cipher functions if fitted with an Intel 8294 from the MCS-85 peripheral family. Other methods, like DES could be implemented in software had they had their algorithm open but they were usually be hardware ppelined implementations which had quite a performance.

Comment: (5) Still, most of the companies just couldn't make their computers competitive in an aggressive market as it was during late 70s and 80s without being fairly priced. And criptography was expensive. However, even criptography can have low standards: LFSR can provide unauthorized use if used as dongle or even as a cipher itself (but not quite strong). Implementations such as this can be found in the 1980 Commodore Super PET, every single Nintendo non-portable console from the NES to the N64 and the Amstrad ACID ic.

Comment: (6) Additionally, arcade companies used to scramble the contents of their ROMs to avoid bootleggers copy their machines while in later 8-16bit of such systems real ciphering was done (for instance, later SNK neo-geo based arcades). This last protections reside in having ASICs to obscure the methods used, had they used standard components bootleggers would have copied even more systems they did.

Comment: (7) But the real game changer was in the concept thad criptography methods had to be open and the keys private. That meant any skilled programmer could implement more complex operations that the former. By then microcomputers had evolved and PCs were the systems with the largest user base ranging from homes, schools, offices, depots and other sensible areas. Not long after that Internet gained widespread use and challenged every single aspect of the concept of privacy people had back then.

Comment: (8) Finally the last but not least factor was the commercialization of Internet. The original designers of the network did not design its protocols to be secure and this caused many troubles to both businesses and clients. Over time and with strong campaigns of conscientation, programmers learned they had to secure the data they were treating so it could not be easily accessed by unauthorized users while older communication protocols were superseedeed by securer ones.

Comment: It's a little before my time, but I have the impression that the [Morris worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_worm), in 1988, was something of a landmark.  It got people's attention as to the possible risks of security vulnerabilities.  The industry obviously took many more years before security became a primary concern, though.

Answer (score 28):

I think you're looking at this from the wrong angle.

It makes more sense to look at it from the perspective of "When did technology from the more enterprise tiers start to flow into the mainstream?"

Things like CP/M, MS-DOS, Windows 3.1x/9x, etc. are products of a world with microcomputers that aren't networked aside from the occasional transient dial-up call to something like a BBS or office server.

I don't know about the earliest entries, but time-sharing operating systems have had user access controls and user/administrator privilege separation since, if not the beginning of interactive computing, then very close. We're talking the 1960s.

Prior to that, security was achieved by having only the trusted humans interact with the computer, and only enter batch jobs that had been vetted.

Windows 2000 was when you started to see security and privilege separation become significant because it was when the Windows NT line started to reach feature parity with the Windows 9x line for **non-**business stuff like 3D acceleration, and Windows NT had been designed as a multi-user competitor to systems like UNIX, based on VMS heritage.

(It also helped that enough of the typically-in-use software and hardware drivers had shifted to the Win32 APIs that switching to an NT kernel with more privilege isolation wouldn't be as likely to break what people were already running.)

Windows 3.1 had a counterpart with user accounts and privilege separation in the short-lived [Windows NT 3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_3.1) ([screenshots](https://guidebookgallery.org/screenshots/winnt31)) and then [Windows NT 3.51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_3.51) ([screenshots](https://guidebookgallery.org/screenshots/winnt351)) ... it just required significantly beefier hardware and wasn't much more compatible with the random hardware drivers and DOS software you already owned than Linux was in the early 2000s.

As for why the transition occurred, probably because the Internet burst into public consciousness during 1995 and 1996 and, by 2000, it was starting to become apparent to both good guys and bad guys that something more robust was needed for machines exposed to a global network and/or downloading random software off random websites.

(Plus, by 2000, hardware had advanced enough that the resource cost of improved security wasn't so painful anymore.)

Comment: Heh, the WinNT 3.1 screenshots appear to have been taken on a system using FAT32 for the filesystem... which is a total and epic fail from a security standpoint unless I'm missing something about how FAT works or WinNT is using some file elsewhere as an access control list or something. (WinNT 3.51 seems to be using NTFS, thankfully.) Also interesting to note the ~2 TB disk in the NT 3.1 screenshot.

Comment: Networked/multiuser systems also used to be far less security-oriented than they are today. The Unix /etc/passwd file needs to be readable by all users to this day, but it used to contain users' password in plaintext rather than hashes. This lack of security orientation also shows up in networking protocols (e.g. SMTP) that originally assumed good faith from all users, but are nowadays easily exploitable.

Comment: @Kaz World-readable plaintext passwords? Good grief.

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 Better than nothing...I guess.

Comment: @Kaz That's not quite right. It needed to be readable to the login process but not to user-level accounts. The problem was anyone with admin access (or a privilege escalation exploit) could still read all the plain-text passwords.

Comment: @Kaz: /etc/passwd doesn't have any passwords visible at all nowadays as those are supposed to be in /etc/shadow.

Comment: /etc/passwd contained hashed passwords at least since the 90s, likely even earlier. The password is used as key to encrypt a known constant string using single DES to obtain the hash ("unix crypt"). This was sufficiently strong when the method was invented, so having the hashes world readable didn't seem like a problem. /etc/passwd is still world readable, because it also contains the user-id to username mapping, but password hashes have since been moved to /etc/shadow (readable by root only), and the hashing scheme has later been upgraded to a more secure methods.

Comment: Per the [man pages for 1st ed. Unix (1971)](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V1/man/man5/passwd.5), passwd "naturally, is inaccessible to anyone but the super--user".

Comment: By the 3rd ed., [the passwords are encrypted](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V3/man/man5/passwd.5) and, as stated in the man page, the file can be world-readable to allow uid-to-name lookups.  (TUHS does not have man pages for the 2nd ed.)

Comment: The Unix system I used in the mid 80's had encrypted passwords. So they've been like that since at least BSD 4.2. The vulnerability was that the passwd file had to be world readable because it didn't just contain the passwords. That means anybody could run the encryption on each word in the Unix dictionary and compare the results to all the passwords (actually, probably needed to do each word separately on each account because of the salts). It was easy to brute force users' passwords that way.

Answer (score 11):

The change over happened when computers were exposed to network environments.

Early multi user systems implemented security out of necessity, so that users couldn't interfere with each other. Enterprise customers were doing that back in the 60s.

On the personal computer front, corporations adopted networks in the 80s and early 90s, Novell NetWare brought security to DOS and Windows machines, again out of necessity. Later Microsoft took over that market with more secure versions of Windows.

For home users the network that really spurred the change was the internet. Malware became a huge problem for single user operating systems with no security model.

Comment: I think a bigger factor was that people started using computers for transactions involving money in a few rather consistent ways, making it practical for malware to capture information that could be used to conduct fraudulent transactions.  On the flip side, many computing platforms and applications have become focused on data harvesting for advertisers, at the expense of both security and performance.

Answer (score 6):

When did cars start adding door locks? :D (rhetorical)

I used to be a BBS SysOp in the 1980s.  Everything was plain text, when callers (users) made accounts, I saw their passwords.   In fact, when I migrated from one BBS software to another, sometimes I would manually re-create people's accounts (and enter their passwords) -- with just a few hundred accounts, that was faster than trying to write some data conversion utility (and sometimes didn't have source code for the new system).

Also I could see what any connected user was doing -- as they were typing things.  And I could hit a hotkey to "jump into chat" with a connected user.  There was a PAGE option, that would make my system beep if someone needed to get a hold of me and get my attention.  Or if I saw a user was struggling to find a file or get a download going, or some kind of issue, I could jump in and try to help them.

I hear what the OP is saying - there was a transition.  And it bugs me that as soon as computing power is there to do a certain thing, now it suddenly becomes a legal imperative to have it done.  In other words, when a CPU was so slow, encryption wasn't important.  It was just an "honor system" when using those online systems.  And users should use good judgement and not use important credentials (or not use the same credentials for each system).  I'm not aware of any "corrupt SysOp" that abused that trust - but I suspect somewhere it did happen (like a SysOp then "posing" as that user, or trying to use that same password on other systems).

Anyhow, I think the transition was for two reasons:  (1) CPUs were slow back then.  Early microcomputers could barely maintain the asynchronous connection and run your terminal emulator program, let alone do anything like compression or encryption on the fly.  We're talking 1-4 MHz CPUs.   (2) Nobody was doing online banking back then.  If you wanted to do business, you gave your home phone number, and mailed checks.  My first experience on the internet was Mosaic, AltaVista, and some Gopher searches - probably on OS/2 in 1994 (and I recall it cost $100 for that couple hours of surfing).   In order to start doing e-commerce, people needed to trust the system was encrypted from just wiresharking people's credit card numbers.  eBay started maybe around 1996? 1997-ish?  We still mailed checks/money orders for awhile, but online banking was coming -- and by then Pentium and 100+ MHz systems were typical.  Remember Stacker?  On the fly compression to save disk space - Microsoft stole their idea and made it part of MS-DOS.  Anyhow, if we could do on-the-fly compression/decompression, the CPUs could also do on-the-fly encryption.

Now... as far as user accounts, such as on a home PC...  Recall Unix/Linux had those three tiers of policies like from day 1 (that octal code on every folder and file, or 777 to just open it up).  MS-DOS (or 86-DOS) never had that.  I think either DR-DOS, or third-party DOS extensions, could add some login stuff during bootup.  I don't even recall logins for OS/2 or Windows for Workgroups (they probably had options for it, but not by default).  I guess it was Vista, c2007/2008 the first time I had to think about a user account at home.    BUT - these days we do hold a lot of personal information on our PCs, and in case anyone breaks in and steals your PC, it definitely is good practice to have an encrypted drive and secured login.  I think in the 1980s, "most" (hopefully) had backups of anything important back on a floppy disk - but that was mostly because hard drives were unreliable, when they started going bad, they'd go bad quickly (as in bad sectors).  These days hard drives are so reliable, and to some extent "self healing" (marking bad sectors and relocating the data on the fly), I don't know anyone "backs up" stuff to a CD or SD-card anymore (maybe some use cloud -- I mirror stuff to a NAS).

Comment: Cars started adding door locks [in the 1940's](https://www.actionlockdoc.com/blog/the-history-of-car-locks/).